# How to install new font on OS X?

Tags: macos, font

How to install new font on OS X to be used across OpenOffice, iWork, OfficeForMac, mail and other word processing applications?

Comment: 1. Download the font 2. Double-click the file 3. Click install 4. Restart any applications that need to use the new font.

Comment: @gentmatt You don't even need to reopen most applications.

Comment: @LauriRanta I'm not sure to which applications this applies (Office '08 ?), but I mentioned this just as precaution.

Answer (score 3):

A third option would be to open the files (for all typefaces), and click the Install Font button in the window, which copies the font files to `~/Library/Fonts/`.

[image]

I usually just move the files manually because I keep each font in their own folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the application `Font Book` which is part of your default OS install in your applications folder.

Open is up, hit the menus, and check out `File > Add Fonts` then navigate to the files in question.

Answer (score 1):

Using Finder, drag the font files to folder `/Library/Fonts`.
Or drag the font files to folder `/Users/<your user name>/Library/Fonts` when you would like to install the fonts for usage in your own account only.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [RightFont](https://rightfontapp.com) to install my fonts, maybe it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify gentmatt's comment, you download the `.ttf` file, double click to open it, then a new dialog shows up with some examples using it, click "install font" in the lower right hand corner, and you're done.

This installs it "for the current user" into your ~/Library/Fonts folder.

Most applications seem to pick it up and use it "next time they refresh the screen" (instantaneously for some), but without restart anyway.